# A White Border appearing while Run

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a window in wpf Application and I have WindowStyle to "None" AllowsTransparency to"False". Because I can't Freely resize window without making it "False". Here is the Problem. Red mark legends the Problem!

[image: Red mark legends the Problem!]

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Orbit__Word.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="524" WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="False" Background="#FF976262">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Orbit_Dat/Metro-Default.jpg" 
                        Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Grid.Background>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,7,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="Orbit® Word" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" 
                   FontFamily="Destroy X" Height="28" Width="107" FontSize="24"/>
        <Grid/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why this border appears and How could I prevent this? Please Help!

Comment: The white board is the Windows 10 Resize Border that gives you something to click on for resizing the window. If you change `ResizeMode="NoResize" on the `<Window>` it should remove the bar, although you'll have to implement your own resize code if you want that functionality.

Comment: Actually after looking around at the link from [mrsargent's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34932239/302677), it looks like you might be able to set `AllowsTransparent=True` and it should work too (Am not sure if you have to also set `ResizeMode=CanResize`... do not have Windows 10 to test with)